# Debugging C++ with Visual Studio debugger

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I want to write an extension for Visual Studio Code (VSCode) which will allow me to debug a C++ program with Visual Studio's native C++ debugger instead of gdb (which currently is the only option VSCode supports). I looked at the [Visual Studio Debugger Extensibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb161718.aspx). But it only explains how you can create a new debug engine and call it from Visual Studio as a front end. What I want to do is the opposite. I want to call the *existing* Visual Studio C++ debug engine from a *different* front end, which happens to be VSCode. There is no documentation on the Internet how I can achieve this. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm on the VSCode team. To use the VS debugger from VSCode, you will need to author a debug adapter extension. [Here's some documentation on getting started](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-debuggers), and [here's the complete debug adapter protocol reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-debugadapter-node).

Try look at some existing implementations to get started:

- [Mock debugger](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mock-debug) – simple example debugger
- [Node debugger](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-node-debug) - node.js debug adapter

For C++, also check out [C++ tools for VSCode](https://web.archive.org/web/20170715151248/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/cc-extension-for-visual-studio-code/).

Hope that helps.

---

**Edit** - Seems I misunderstood the problem. Here are some thoughts on consuming the VS C++ debugger from an external application.

To my knowledge, Visual C++ does not have public APIs or interfaces that allows external programs to easily interface with them. Other languages have better stories, since they often leverage external libraries or were designed with documented debugger protocols. The [GDB machine interface](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_211.html) is a good example of this sort of design.

My best suggestion is that you could try to leverage the [Visual Studio Env.DTE interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.debugger.aspx) to control VS programmatically. EnvDTE is not well documented and may not be exactly what you are after, but it is pretty powerful.

Comment: Hi Matt. I know about VSCode's debug protocol and understand that I'll have to write a Debug Adapter. Problem is I don't know exactly how my Debug Adapter will call Visual Studio's debug engine. That's what I want some help with (it's kinda a question for the visual studio team)

Comment: Sorry, I totally misunderstood what part of the problem you are asking about. I've added some thoughts consuming the VS C++ debugger from an external program. In short, for Visual C++, I'm not sure this is possible but EnvDTE is worth a shot. Other languages/debuggers have much better stories

Comment: Thanks Matt. No wonder there isn't much on the Internet on the subject. I'll try and look at the EnvDTE approach (although I have little hope because it's meant for automating Visual Studio not the debug engine).